# How can I get a iterable resultset from the database using pdo, instead of a large array?

Tags: php, database, pdo, resultset, iterable

I'm using [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) inside a database abstraction library function `query` that I've made.

I'm using [`fetchAll()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php), which if you have a lot of results, is supposed to get memory intensive, so I want to provide an argument to toggle between a fetchAll associative array and a pdo result set that can be iterated over with `foreach` and requires less memory (somehow).

I remember hearing about this, and I searched through the PDO docs, but I couldn't find any useful way to do that.

**Does anyone know how to get an iterable resultset back from PDO instead of just a flat array?  And am I right that using an iterable resultset will be easier on memory?**

I'm using Postgresql, if it matters in this case.

.

.

.

*The current query function is as follows, just for clarity.*

```
/**
 * Running bound queries on the database.
 *
 * Use: query('select all from players limit :count', array('count'=>10));
 * Or: query('select all from players limit :count', array('count'=>array(10, PDO::PARAM_INT)));
**/
function query($sql_query, $bindings=array()){
 DatabaseConnection::getInstance();
 $statement = DatabaseConnection::$pdo->prepare($sql_query);
 foreach($bindings as $binding => $value){
  if(is_array($value)){
   $statement->bindParam($binding, $value[0], $value[1]);
  } else {
   $statement->bindValue($binding, $value);
  }
 }
 $statement->execute();
 // TODO: Return an iterable resultset here, and allow switching between array and iterable resultset.
 return $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 
}
```

Comment: Isn't that exactly what `fetch()` does? http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php it's not exactly iterable with `foreach` but works fine in a `while` loop.

Comment: Not really?  'cause Fetch actually performs an iteration step.  I guess that means that the statement itself might be iterable after `->execute()` somehow, which might be closer to what I'm looking for.

Comment: you can iterate over query(), but not sure how youd work that in the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like I've found my solution in the form of the PDOStatement object itself, i.e. after doing a `$statement->execute();` You can simply pass along the `$statement` object and foreach over that object.  Can't use it as an array, but can do just about everything else with it.